# interpreting django language

Tags: django

I'm creating a simple blog using this tutorial http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html.
I'm new to django and i'm having problem following some steps inside this tutorial.
I'm trying my best to understand, I sometimes just don't understand it. I tried getting the source code but the file is corrupted.

The steps I need interpreting are:

> Post Page
>
> We’ll also need a separate page for each post with visitors' comments
>   and full post text (if we later decide to limit post body shown on
>   front page). Here's how I plan to set things up: the url will be
>   `/blog/post/{pk}/` where `pk` is the primary key of post's object;
>   template will be called `post.html` and the view function will be
>   `post()`.
>
> The main listing will show a simple link:
>
> ```
> <div class="commentlink">
>     <a href="{% url blog.views.post post.pk %}">Comments</a>
> </div>
> ```

I'm sorry if this isn't an appropriate question.

I'm up to the post page step and I just don't know what to do!

my views.py

```
 from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage
 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from blog.models import *
 from django.core.context_processors import csrf
 from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

 def main(request):
     """Main listing."""
     posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")
     paginator = Paginator(posts, 2)

     try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
     except ValueError: page = 1

     try:
         posts = paginator.page(page)
     except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
         posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

     return render_to_response("list.html", dict(posts=posts, user=request.user))


 def post(request, pk):
     """Single post with comments and a comment form."""
     post = Post.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
     comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
     d = dict(post=post, comments=comments, form=CommentForm(), user=request.user)
     d.update(csrf(request))
     return render_to_response("post.html", d)
 def add_comment(request, pk):
     """Add a new comment."""
     p = request.POST

     if p.has_key("body") and p["body"]:
         author = "Anonymous"
         if p["author"]: author = p["author"]

         comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))
         cf = CommentForm(p, instance=comment)
         cf.fields["author"].required = False

         comment = cf.save(commit=False)
         comment.author = author
         comment.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:add_comment'))
```

Comment: That's not a step, that's a *piece* of a step.

Comment: Yeah , I done the projectapp so I though , I might be ready for lightbird but their some steps which doesn't make sense. Is it ok , If i send you the code in 30 min?

Comment: I am new to django to and I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) I found this much more descriptive on the how and why then the link you posted (with repect to the creator). So I do not have a direct answer to you question but maybe the link can help you. Paul.

Comment: Thank for the help Paul but I done that app.I'm trying to do more advance apps so I went back to lightbird

Comment: Wait @cathy , How Do I fix this error when I click on add comment  .Reverse for 'blog.views.post' with arguments '(u'3',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Reading the lightbird page again I noticed this. **template will be called post.html** have you created the template?

Comment: Thank you for helping me also PPaual :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For template:

```
{% url blog:add_comment id_here %}
```

For view

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:view_name'))


def add_comment(request, pk):
    .......
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("blog:post", args=[pk]))
```

Comment: Ok , so I should take the add_comment function from models and put it in views?

Comment: Alright . I moved the add_comment fuction int views and edited     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:add_comment')) and I get this error Reverse for 'add_comment' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: cathy i got another error NoReverseMatch at /cool/add_comment/1/

Reverse for 'post' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. . what does this error mean?

Comment: it was  before   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:add_comment'))
then I changed it too     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("blog:post")) .

Comment: Wait cathy , When I submit a comment . It brings me to NoReverseMatch at /cool/add_comment/1/ but when I return to the page and refresh . The comment is added

Comment: Ok2x I see it now my answer is incomplete so I updated it. Sorry my mistake I forgot to put the pk. I think it will be work now

Comment: can I ask you cathy how long have you been a django developer for? you are amazing in django

Comment: No, not really. My boss train me until now and he wants me to study class based views and how to arrange the codes of django for advanced. I think it's been 9 months.

Comment: thank you very much again @cathy . The way i'm trying to learn through django is trying to put an app and when it's work . I will try to pin point where this function and that go. Is that a good way to learn?

Comment: How stick in the original way without depending on template tags or third party apps. How to make an app in the fastest way. How to make your codes clean and arrange. How to refactor it. For now my level is a beginner. I'm not an expert.

Comment: Oh :( if your a beginner then this make me an ant

Comment: Maybe I don't know because I did not use django tutorial or lightbird or any other tutorial there. My boss train me on the spot without knowing django and it's really give me a headache for the first time I use Django.

Comment: Don't worry you will learn. If you do programming in the past. You will learn it less than a month. The difficult part is if you don't have an experienced person who will guide you for that

Comment: Yeah , I have no experience in programming and this is my first language.I live in australia and their hardly anyone maybe less than 100 who know django because they all know java etc. I don't have anyone to teach me but all I have is just resources from the internet and lucky people like you to give me boost on my journey to learning django

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24622/discussion-between-cathy-and-supersheep1)